# Copy one database in SQL Server 2016 to another in SQL Server 2012 using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, copy, transfer

I need to copy data from one database from SQL Server 2016 to another database in SQL Server 2012 using asp.net C#. How can I do it? Is it possible to copy data between two versions of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes.  Use BulkCopy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't create a backup and restore it. Maybe you could use task -> generate Scripts  -> Choose Objects ->..."  Options: Schema and Data

Comment: Just tried the method I mentioned above and it seemed to work. I don't know about all of the security wiring. @jdweng's solution sounds better (assuming it can cross versions)

Comment: You can make a backup of the database anytime and then copy do another PC.  You can also make archives of database using the command line utilities that com with sql server like sqlcmd.exe and bcp.exe.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be C#? You should try [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)

Comment: thank you @jdweng . BulkCopy works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jdweng is right. BulkCopy works well.

you can use [a very good example in this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-copy-in-sql-server-using-c-sharpnet1).